# Implement keyboard shortcuts in MS word Office.js add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm trying to implement a feature in a Word add-in where I track what the user typing in MS Word and then perform automatic replacements.  For example, the user could type

```
:smile: :frown:
```

and I would automatically replace them with

```
:) :(
```

I've implemented a handler to receive `documentSelectionChanged` events, and I'm currently using the following event handler:

```
function refLabelShortcut() {
  var range, results, par;
  Word.run(function (context) {
    range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.paragraphs.load('items');
    return context.sync()
    .then(function() {
      par = range.paragraphs.items[0];
      console.log(par.text); // THIS WORKS!
      results = par.search('the*', {matchWildCards: true});
      //results = par.search('the');
      results.load('items'); // SOMETHING WRONG HERE?
      console.log('1');
    })
    .then(context.sync)
    .then(function() {
      console.log('2a'); // DOESN'T GET TO THIS LINE :(
      console.log(results.items.length);
      console.log('2b');
    });
  });
}
```

The above code works when the search isn't a wildcard one.  I've commented out the non-wildcard search so you can see what does work.

When you do the wildcard search, the console shows:

```
[text of the matching paragraph]
1
```

and that's it.  So the code doesn't get to the last `then` function.

Any idea why this doesn't work with a wildcard search?  Is there a mistake with the `results.load('items')` line?

Comment: Can you insert this into the function? `range.insertText(":smile:", ":)")`

Comment: @Mech, according to the [insertText documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#inserttext-text--insertlocation-), it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Range.paragraphs is a collection object, you can't load a collection object, so `range.load('paragraphs')` doesn't do anything. In order to read the items of the paragraph collection, you have to load the items (or some property of the paragraph object). Try:

`range.paragraphs.load('items');`

Comment: Hi Rich, I added two more `load` statements to my second example, but `items` are still not loaded at the last log statement.  Any more ideas?

Comment: delete the line `range.load('paragraphs');` Also does the line console.log(par.text); now run?

Comment: Rich, `console.log(par.text)` has always worked for me even before your suggestion.  The part that doesn't work is then doing a search of the paragraph.  `results.items` isn't loaded.  I also removed `context.load(results);`

Comment: The line `.then(context.sync())` should be `.then(context.sync)`. When I make that change, along with the others I recommended, your code works for me.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I fixed that but it still doesn't work with a wildcard search.  I simplified my question to focus on the most recent code.  When you run the current code with the wildcard search, do you get the `console.log` statements in the last `then` function?

Comment: Yes. Those `console.log` line` run correctly. Everything works. If you aren't already, you should be using the [Script Lab tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) to prototype your code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  It doesn't work for Office 365 on Mac. Let me know if it is worth filing a bug report somewhere.

Comment: Create an issue at: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues